# Gremlin ConcurrentModificationException terminates Node.js server when writing to AWS Neptune, never reaches 'catch' clauses

Tags: node.js, gremlin, amazon-neptune

node: 16.20.2
gremlin: 3.6.5

```
ResponseError: Server error: 
{
  "detailedMessage": "Failed to complete Insert operation for a Vertex due to conflicting concurrent operations. Please retry. 0 transactions are currently rolling back.",
  "requestId": "804258c5-6b10-4abc-8d7f-659acaad0f15",
  "code": "ConcurrentModificationException"
} (500)
```

The code provided below successfully inserts data into AWS Neptune most of the time, but it sporadically fails, which is expected. Unfortunately, I'm unable to reach a catch clause because the Gremlin driver error terminates the server. I've attempted various catch clauses in different scopes, but the issue persists.
The error rate was much higher when the function was an async promise.

(**Edit**: refactor as suggested by Taylor Riggan, the issue persists.)

```js
  private insertOrUpdateEdge(edge) {
    const availableSince = new Date(edge['available_since']);

    let insertQuery = __.V(edge.from).as('from').V(edge.to).addE(edge.label).from_('from').property(t.id, edge.id);

    insertQuery = this.addProperties(insertQuery, edge);
    let insertOrUpdateQuery;
    try {
      insertOrUpdateQuery = this.g
        .E(edge.id)
        .fold()
        .coalesce(unfold(), insertQuery)
        .has('available_since', P.gt(availableSince))
        .property('available_since', availableSince)
        .next();
    } catch (err) {
      this.insertOrUpdateEdge(edge);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It appears like you are not adding the Terminal Step [1] to the query until the `finally{}` block.  The Terminal Step is needed to send the query to the database.  You should be using the Terminal Step (`next()` in this case) in the `try{}` block.  If an exception is thrown, then it will be caught in the `catch{}` block at that point.

[1] https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#terminal-steps

Comment: I still get these errors after the refactoring but less - they still won't reach the 'catch' hook

Comment: What size instance are you using and how may concurrent queries are you pushing to Neptune at any given time?  Be sure that you're using the sizing guidelines here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/instance-types.html.

Comment: Also, you're not going to be able to use a catch to retry the query.  I would suggest creating a query function, along with a reconnect/retry function that gets called in the catch to handle the retry.  Our Node.js example for AWS Lambda has a good representation of this:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/lambda-functions-examples.html#lambda-functions-examples-javascript